# single instance activity closed after app minimized

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

i developed an one android app , it's one activity is singleinstace if it's visible on screen , and minimized app i open from launcher app open from launcher activity , but other activities are not behave just like single instance activity.

single instance activity flow :

splash (finish) -  mpin(finish)  -  kochionecard(single instace) 
app is minimized i click to launcher icon open splash activity

other activity flow
splash (finish) -  mpin(finish)  -  kochionecard(single instace)  - Addmoney(normal)
app is minimized i click to launcher icon open Addmoney activity , but i pressed back app is exit

i dont know why did happen can anyone explain me how i wil solved those problem

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.kochione"
android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name=".KochiApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="eb2d72fbddd84bfcf684dd47dcc39e19c189b685" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MpinActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WelcomeSignupActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.dashboard.ProfileActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SosActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.dashboard.KochiOneCardActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">




    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.kochi1card.ServiceRequestActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.kochi1card.OfferDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.kochi1card.NotificationDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.kochi1card.StatementActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.kochi1card.IssuanceCenterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.dashboard.kochi1card.addmoney.AddMoneyActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.kochi1card.addmoney.PaymentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.kochi1card.MyBalanceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.qrcode.MetroTicketActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.dashboard.qrcode.QrMpinActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.qrcode.QrTicketActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.qrcode.tripPlanner.TripPlannerDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.qrcode.tripPlanner.TripPlannerTimeTableActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.dashboard.KochiMetroActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kochi_metro"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activities.dashboard.bottomsheet.QRTicketHistoryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <receiver android:name=".receivers.TicketCancelReceiver" />

    <service
        android:name=".services.TicketCancelService"
        android:exported="false"></service>
</application>
```

i want if i minimized app single instance activity resumed just like other activities.

Comment: can you post your entire AndroidManifest.xml please.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: i want to do app minimized resume activity which is lauch mode singleinstace